# Brother HL-L8360CDW printer installation failure on 18.04 LTS

Tags: printing, brother, cups-lpd

I am trying to install a [Brother HL-L8360CDW printer](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll8360cdw_us_eu_as&os=128). My ASUS PC w/ 16 GB RAM, 250 GB SSD, and Intel UHD Graphics 620 runs Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x64.

I have downloaded many drivers on recommendation, and it still will not work. I have looked at many questions similar to mine, with no results to date.

Can anyone assist with this?  I am not literate with computer language, and don't understand modern computer terms.  I just need to get this fixed, if possible.  Brother cannot help because they don't support Linux.

Comment: This page on CUPS https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html may help. 
 Brother Linux drivers for Ubuntu and Debian are at https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll8360cdw_us_eu_as&os=128  Have you tried Brother's Linux install tool https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll8360cdw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625 ? Please click [edit] and advise the results which appear when you try it. Please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit] to put your results in your question.